# need some help about codeigniter route

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, routes

Is there a way to make the route in codeigniter work like that in symfony?

Cause in there you can rename the route **path** and it still wouldn't affect your output cause what you call is the route **name** not the route **path** unlike in codeigniter.

For example, in symfony, routes are set like this:

```
news_index:
    path:      /news
    defaults:  { _controller: CmsBundle:News:index }

news_view:
    path:      /news/view/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: CmsBundle:News:view }
```

and then I can access that in my template by calling the route **name**, not the route **path**

```
<?php 
    // outputs: /news
    echo $view['router']->generate('news_index');

    // outputs: /news/view/1
    echo $view['router']->generate('news_view',array('id' => $news_id)); 
?>
```

so if I change the route **path** it wouldn't affect the way i call it in my code because i'm calling the route **name**, all it will do is change the output:

```
news_index:
    path:      /articles
    defaults:  { _controller: CmsBundle:News:index }

news_view:
    path:      /articles/item/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: CmsBundle:News:view }
```

still same code but output is changed

```
<?php 

    // outputs: /articles
    echo $view['router']->generate('news_index');

    // outputs: /articles/item/1
    echo $view['router']->generate('news_view',array('id' => $news_id)); 
?>
```

while in codeigniter, if i set my route like this:

```
$route['news'] = 'NewsController';
$route['news/view/(:num)'] = 'NewsController/view/$1';
```

the only way i know to call it is by the route path:

```
<?php
    echo anchor('news');
    echo anchor('news/view'.$news_id);
?>
```

and if I change my path, I would have to change what I wrote in view as well. That would be a hassle. So I'm wondering if there could be a way to make it work like in symfony. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me. And I apologize if my explanation is not clear. English is not my mother tongue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is blog post available from **@*kennyk*** that describes his approach to symfony-like named routes using a router extension.

The article is called [**Easy Reverse Routing with CodeIgniter**](http://codefury.net/2010/09/easy-reverse-routing-with-codeigniter/).

I guess that's what you're looking for.